# Getting Parsley 2 working with Bootstrap 4

Tags: parsley.js, twitter-bootstrap-4

By default, Parsley only handles updating a single element's class (usually the input field in which the invalid entry is). However, with Bootstrap 4 we must update both the form-group and the input field classes to render them with the validation icons. Otherwise, only the border colour is changed.

How can I use Parsley to correctly, completely style my input fields when validating user input in the client?

Answer (score 4):

In order to correctly style Bootstrap 4 with Parsley, you must modify the classes of the `div.form-group` surrounding your `input` fields (assuming you want the validation icons, like I did).

According to the documentation you need to add `.has-success` or `.has-danger` to the `div.form-group` and then specify `form-control-success` and `form-control-danger` respectively to the input fields.

However, Parsley only supports updating the class on a single element by default. Fortunately, it supports event binding, so with a little function added to the end of your parsley.js file, we can handle updating the div.form-group styles when the user has fixed a validation error.

First configure Parsley:

```
errorClass: "form-control-danger",
successClass: "form-control-success"
```

These are the correct classes to apply to the input fields, which Parsley works on by default. Next, append the following to the `parsley.(min).js` file.

```
window.Parsley.on('field:validated', function(e) {
    if (e.validationResult.constructor!==Array) {
        this.$element.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger').addClass('has-success');
    } else {
        this.$element.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
    }
});
```

The above will listen for when fields have been validated, and, hence update the relevant `div.form-group` according to the Bootstrap 4 documentation to ensure that the input field gets rendered appropriately.